# Exception in component tJavaFlex_1 (time) java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1 javatflex and tmemorizerows

Tags: java, talend

I have a job in talend where i need to count the number of days a transition from one element to another takes and i used tmemorizerows and tjavaflex to accomplish it. i wrote this code in the tjavaflex and got this error:

```
if(id_folder_tMemorizeRows_1[0].equals(id_folder_tMemorizeRows_1[1]))

 {  count=created_at_tMemorizeRows_1[0].getTime() - start_date_tMemorizeRows_1[0].getTime()/(24*60*60*1000);   
 }
   else
   {
   if(id_departement_tMemorizeRows_1[0].equals(                                       id_departement_tMemorizeRows_1[1]))
    { count=created_at_tMemorizeRows_1[1].getTime() - created_at_tMemorizeRows_1[0].getTime()/(24*60*60*1000);
    }
    else {
count+=created_at_tMemorizeRows_1[1].getTime()- created_at_tMemorizeRows_1[0].getTime()/(24*60*60*1000);
    }
   } 
   System.out.println(count+id_folder_tMemorizeRows_1[0]);
```

```
**Démarrage du job time a 10:52 06/08/2020.
[statistics] connecting to socket on port 3621
[statistics] connected
Exception in component tJavaFlex_1 (time)
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1
    at permis_det.time_0_1.time.tMysqlInput_1Process(time.java:3280)
    at permis_det.time_0_1.time.runJobInTOS(time.java:5449)
    at permis_det.time_0_1.time.main(time.java:5298)
[statistics] disconnected
Job time terminé à 10:52 06/08/2020. [Code sortie=1]**
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you print this objects

```
created_at_tMemorizeRows_1[0].getTime() - start_date_tMemorizeRows_1[0]
```

This will help you figure out which arrays you are trying to access has no index you are trying to access.

Comment: did you try doing this?